# How to unlock swift file (Xcode)?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, macos

When I try to write something in the assisted editor in Xcode 7.1, there's a error message that I can't change the code (can't unlock it), because I don't own it! Do you know how to let me have access to it?

Answer (score 5):

I solved my problem by doing this

1. Go up to the folder containing the project in your Finder.
2. Right Click > Get Info
3. Go to the bottom of the Info pane, and click the little lock, type in your password when prompted.
4. Then, change permissions for yourself to read+write.
5. Click the little gear below, and apply to all enclosed items.

Close the lock once you are finished!

**OR**

Change the value of "Compiler for C/C++/Objective-C" to Default Compiler under BUILD OPTIONS